# Selecting an element close to current element

Tags: jquery, html

Am trying to select the element after the element am working and retrieve its class, but i keep the undefined error
this is the html

```
<div class="clearfix">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><span class="form-validation-status"></span>
               </div>
```

And this is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var username_field = $("input[name='username']");
    var email_field = $("#_email");
   var host_url = "http://localhost/ur/";
        //Check if the username is already in use
        username_field.blur(function() {
            var _username = username_field.val();
            var uri = host_url+"accounts/signup/is_username_exist/"+_username;
            $.ajax({ 
                url:uri,
                type:'GET',
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data) {
                                   var test = $(this).closest("span").attr("class");
                                   alert(test);
                } 
            });
});
```

Its keeps alerting as undefined what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `next()` not `closest()`

And `$(this)` in your success handler refers to `data`, you need to define the variable earlier in order to fetch it there.

```
var $theSpan = $("input[name='username']").next();
alert($theSpan.attr('class'));
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
username_field.siblings('.form-validation-status');
```

> **Description**: Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

You could also use .next() but it implies the element you search is the next element, so it will break if it is placed before.

Answer (score 0):

Closest() searches up the dom tree, try using next()